# Sidebar isn't 100% height bootstrap+reactjs

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I created this sidebar using bootstrap 5 and it doesn't fill the whole height of the page any ideas?

```
<div className="container-fluid">
<div className="row flex-nowrap ">
<div className="col-auto col-md-3 col-xl-2 px-sm-2 px-0 bg-dark ">
<div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center align-items-sm-start px-3 pt-2 
 text-white min-vh-100 position-fixed">
</div></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use **position-fixed** like below

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row flex-nowrap ">
    <div class="col-auto col-md-3 col-xl-2 px-sm-2 px-0 bg-dark position-fixed">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center align-items-sm-start px-3 pt-2 text-white min-vh-100">
            <h1>Menu</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="height:1000px; width:500px; color: red; background:green;">
    </div>
</div>
```